# Best way to extract longitude/latitude from a character vector in R

Tags: r, regex

trying to separate values in this character string in R so I get both longitude and latitude.

What's the best way to go about doing this? using a gsub on regex?

e.g.

```
"POINT (-90.10051372 29.97596117)"
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are probably dealing with an `sf` object, here is an `sf` solution:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(sf)
data.frame(a = "POINT (-90.10051372 29.97596117)") %>% 
  st_as_sf(wkt = "a") %>% 
  st_coordinates()

#          X        Y
#1 -90.10051 29.97596
```

Or, more lengthy but maybe more flexible:

```r
st_as_sf(data.frame(a = "POINT (-90.10051372 29.97596117)"),
         wkt = "a") %>% 
  mutate(lon = st_coordinates(.)[,1],
        lat = st_coordinates(.)[,2]) %>% 
  st_drop_geometry()
```

Comment: Short of calling `sf::st_coordinates` twice, can you capture it into a list-column and extract the individual components?

Comment: Actually ... why do you need the `mutate`? Running `st_as_sf(..) %>% st_coordinates()` should return a simple frame (names `X` and `Y`, can use a renaming). (Perhaps OCD or sloppy-looking, but `st_as_sf(..) |> sf::st_coordinates() |> \`colnames<-\`(c("lon", "lat"))`

Comment: Yes. I was about to add this solution. Just figured it out now

Comment: This seems likely to be the most "general" in that other SF-like entries (other than `POINT`) will almost certainly be handled transparently/elegantly. I suspect the regex solutions below (including mine) _may_ be able to do it, I don't know enough about the other options and use-case to know how robust regex will be here. Nice.

Answer (score 3):

If you have multiple strings, you can use `strcapture` to return a `data.frame`:

```r
vec <- c("POINT (-90.10051372 29.97596117)", "POINT (-91.10051372 28.97596117)")
strcapture("\\(([-0-9.]+)\\s+([-0-9.]+)", vec, proto = list(lon = 1,lat = 1))
#         lon      lat
# 1 -90.10051 29.97596
# 2 -91.10051 28.97596
```

Walk-through:

- Pattern:

  ```
  \\(([-0-9.]+)\\s+([-0-9.]+)
  ^^^                         literal left-paren
     ^^^^^^^^^^    ^^^^^^^^^^ groups of pos/neg numbers
               ^^^^           blank-space
  ```

  We can add a right-paren `\\)` to the end of the pattern for good measure, not sure if it adds much.
- `proto=` is purely to match each `(..)` pattern-group with a column name, and the values in the proto define the class/type, the actual values here don't matter (`proto=c(lon=999,lat=198282)` produce the same results; `proto=c(lon="",lat=9)` would produce a string class for `lon`, not what we want/need). If the class used within `proto=` does not work, for instance the pattern group captures something non-number-like, then it will be `NA`.

Answer (score 1):

The trick is in the regex.

```r
x <- "POINT (-90.10051372 29.97596117)"
y <- sub("^[^\\(]+\\(([^\\)]+)\\)$", "\\1", x)
p <- as.numeric(strsplit(y, " ")[[1]])
p
#> [1] -90.10051  29.97596
```

<sup>Created on 2022-09-23 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Explanation:

Comment: Thanks, is there a way to figure out the regex pattern or is it a matter of just learning the lingo?

Comment: @Jean-PaulAzzopardi It's a matter of learning :).

Comment: An overview can be had by taking the regex and string over to [regex101](https://regex101.com/), but remains a matter of learning.

Answer (score 1):

Another approach:

```
gsub('([A-Z]+ \\()(-?[0-9.]+)\\s([0-9.]+)\\)', '\\2 \\3', "POINT (-90.10051372 29.97596117)")
[1] "-90.10051372 29.97596117"
```